# Retrieving Last comment from joining 3 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Having the follow tables examples:

```
JOBS    
   jobid 
   jobname

COMMENTS  
   jobid 
   userid 
   comment 
   date

USERS   
   userid 
   name
```

I need to retrieve the last comment from each jobid
I've been trying distinct and such but no luck so far.
the jobid can be multiple times in the comments table(multiple comments etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as date from a comment and a jobID is unique this will work fine.  If not then this answer will get you the most recent comment, including ties.

```
select comment, jobid
from (select max(date) as MaxDate, jobid from comments group by jobid) x
inner join comments c
on c.jobid = x.jobid
and c.date = x.MaxDate
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the replies,saw this too late now :P I ended up "discovering" 
OUTER APPLY(SELECT...) to select the one row I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ROW_NUMBER() to select the last comment per jobid:

```
SELECT jobid, userid, comment, date
FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY jobid ORDER BY date DESC)'RowRank'
      FROM COMMENTS
     )sub
WHERE RowRank = 1
```

The ROW_NUMBER() function assigns a number to each row based on some criteria, the numbering starts at 1 for each item in the `PARTITION BY` section, and of course the `ORDER BY` determines the order.  The advantage of using `ROW_NUMBER()` is that you don't need a self-join like you would with `MAX()`.

If you then wanted to JOIN to the other tables to get all the info:

```
SELECT c.jobid, j.jobname, c.userid, u.username, c.comment, c.date
FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY jobid ORDER BY date DESC)'RowRank'
      FROM COMMENTS
     ) c
JOIN jobs j
  ON c.jobid = j.jobid
JOIN users u
  ON c.userid = u.userid
WHERE c.RowRank = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would reccomend adding a COMMENTS.ID.

Then look at the max of the COMMENTS.ID.

Alternatly you could

```
SELECT JOBID, MAX(DATE) FROM COMMENTS GROUP BY JOBID
```

Then you could join the above view to your COMMENTS table to find the max date. You will need a timestamp on the COMMENTS.DATE.

T